# .NET RegEx Help for string matching

Tags: .net, regex

I need some help with regular expression.

I need to search for "Android 2.2.x" where x can be 1-9 in a string so I created this RegEx
Androind 2.2.\d{1} This works fine.

Now I want to find Android 2.2 in the in the string

If I search using Regex "Androind 2.2" it matches both "Android 2.2" and "Android 2.2.x" But I want regex to match only "Android 2.2"

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks,

Comment: FWIW: You don't need to do `\d{1}` if you just need one digit, `\d` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative lookahead.  `"Android 2.2(?!\.\d)"` matches `"Android 2.2"` but not `"Android 2.2.1"`, `"Android 2.2.2"`, `"Android 2.2.10"`, etc.  It will also match `"Android 2.2."` if the next character is not a digit or the end of the `string` is reached.

See [Grouping Constructs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your help. "Android 2.2(?!\.\d)" works for all the scenarios.

Comment: This will match "Android 2.2" in "Android 2.22". Use the lookahead `(?!\.?\d)` to prevent that.

Comment: Note that `"Android 2.2(?!\.\d)"` also matches `"Android 2.20"`, so if you need to future-proof yourself for 18 versions from now you might try `"Android 2.2(?!\.?\d)"` (make the period in the assertion optional).

Comment: You guys are amazing. I need to spend more time learning RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

If this string Android 2.2 is followed by end of string, you can include $ after the pattern which matches the end of string.

Otherwise, you can do something like Android 2.2[^0-9.] to make sure that this string is not followed by dot or digits.

One argument against the second case is that you could have a string like
"You are using Andoid 2.2." Where the last . is there to just end a sentence... Would you like to match that string as well?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. $ option will not work because there would be more text around the "Android 2.2"

Android 2.2 can be anywhere in the string.

Comment: As far second option Android "2.2[^0-9.]" it doesn't find a match for "test Android 2.2"

Answer (score 0):

Just to toss out another approach, if you need to provide different behavior for different versions you could do this:

```
string pattern = @"Android (?<major>\d+)\.(?<minor>\d+)(\.(?<revision>\d+))?";
Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);

if (match.Success)
{
    int major = int.Parse(match.Groups["major"].Value);
    int minor = int.Parse(match.Groups["minor"].Value);
    int revision;

    if (!int.TryParse(match.Groups["revision"].Value, out revision))
        revision = 0;

    if (major == 2 && minor == 2)
    {
        if (revision == 0)
        {
            // Process version 2.2
        }
        else
        {
            // Process version 2.2.x, where x > 0
        }
    }
}
```

That will match a major version followed by a minor version optionally followed by a revision, and give you access to each of those three numbers.  Note that if no revision is specified it's treated the same as if it were 0 (i.e. `"Android 2.2" == "Android 2.2.0"`).

You can also use the [`Version` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.version.aspx) to do some of the work, like this:

```
string pattern = @"Android (?<version>\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?)";
Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);

if (match.Success)
{
    Version version = Version.Parse(match.Groups["version"].Value);

    if (version.Major == 2 && version.Minor == 2)
    {
        if (version.Build < 1)
        {
            // Process version 2.2
        }
        else
        {
            // Process version 2.2.x, where x > 0
        }
    }
}
```

There the third number component is called "Build", not "Revision".  Note that the [`Build` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.version.build.aspx) returns 0 if the value is 0 and -1 if the value is not specified.